# How to compile an executable from Haskell Stack build?

Tags: haskell, compilation, executable, haskell-stack

```
|-aseCswk2
  |-app
    |-Main.hs
  |-src
    |-Libs.hs
  |-test
    |-Spec.hs
  |-aseCswk2.cabal
  |-Setup.hs
  |-package.yaml
...
```

So i have a Haskell project that uses a Stack build system and is laid out as the example above. If i use `$ stack test` then my functions in my Libs.hs file are tested with the cases in my Spec.hs file. If i use `$ stack build` then my file builds successfully and i can use the functions inside `$ stack ghci`.

However, i want to create an executable of the my Main.hs file but don't know how this is possible. I have tried compiling it using `$ ghc Main.hs` inside the app directory but get an error saying 'Failed to load interface for Lib' even though i have included it as an import. I have also tried `$stack build aseCswk2:exe:aseCswk2-exe` but no `.o` files are created to run.

Comment: You can run the program with `stack run`. The files are constructed, in a hidden directory named `.stack-world`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks that's run my code

Comment: if you for example run `stack build` it prints at the last line the location of the executable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell-stack builds the executable in the hidden `.stack-work` directory. You can find out where the binaries are located that `stack` uses with:

```
$ stack path --local-install-root
/haskell/app/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/3fa5b3c3fbcd473981eef72c68d572129654cbb7c23af146b50d90e29c41b62f/8.6.5
```

In this directory, there is, if you build the application, a `bin/` directory where the binary is located that has been built.

You can also run the application with:

```
$ stack run
```

Comment: This command is not described in the introductory documentation of stack here: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/
Is there a way to change that? Or where to request the change?

Comment: @exchange `stack path` is documented in the advanced reference: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/path_command/